# Why am I being rate limited by this Tweepy script?

Tags: python, tweepy

I am just writing a simply 'grab followers' script in Python, using tweepy. When I run the script, everything works fine. Does what it needs to. Though I am being rate limited very heavily. Almost instantly, it seems.

I run other scripts through tweepy, hell I've scraped nearly 800 accounts' tweets before being rate limited previously. Multiple times even.

Can someone shed some light on this? My account was even suspended, temporarily, last night for simply trying to let it finish :-\

```
import tweepy

APP_KEY = ''
APP_SECRET = ''
result = []

auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

if not api:
    print "Didn't Authenticate!"
    sys.exit(-1)

def get_followers(screen_name, filename):
    result = []

    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=screen_name).pages():
        result.extend(page)

    write_to = open(filename, 'w')

    for num in result:
        name = api.get_user(num)
        write_to.write(str(name.screen_name) + '\n')

    write_to.write(str(len(result)))
    write_to.close()

user_input = raw_input('Please enter Twitter name to get followers, or hit enter to use default file:')

if len(user_input) == 0:
    user_input = 'names.txt'

    for name in user_input:
        file_name = str(name) + '.txt'
        get_followers(name, file_name)

else:
    file_name = str(user_input) + '.txt'
    get_followers(user_input, file_name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `followers/id` endpoint. The rate limit is 15 requests in a 15 minute window. See docs [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits). Try making the request once every minute and you should be fine.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a low threshold. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Setting the `count` parameter to 5000 should help.

Comment: Interesting. Basically, so I wouldn't have to make so many calls?

I've actually reworked it a little bit as well, so it doesn't need to convert the id to screen_name anymore. That was sort of silly anyways.